# Can Sentry be run under passenger WSGI (dreamhost)

Tags: python, django, passenger, virtualenv, sentry

I am trying to get [sentry](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry) running on my dreamhost server.  Dreamhost uses passenger wsgi to serve python frameworks, like django. I am able to get django apps running.

I am using virtualenv and I install sentry using pip, so all the code for sentry sits under the virtualenv directory.  The instructions given for sentry doesn't use the `startproject` to create a directory that you can place somewhere for the `passenger_wsgi.py` file to find.

The sentry website gives examples of the program running under Nginx and uWSGI, but I am limited to (in this case) to apache and passenger wsgi.

Is it possible to run sentry under dreamhost's configuration and if so how does one pass things in like the config file to get it working.  I have been able to locally start and interact with sentry, using :

```
sentry --config=/home/user/.sentry/sentry.conf.py start
```

so I know that all the dependencies are present on the host system

Answer (score 3):

OK it looks like I was over thinking it, I forgot from a python perspective  the file `wsgi.py` (which is found in the sentry directory) is called as `sentry.wsgi` when imported as a module.  I was confused by sentry being a module that was downloaded from pip and how to access it. This is the reduced solution that works:

`passenger_wgsi.py`

```
import sys, os
INTERP = "/home/user/.virtualenv/sentry2/bin/python" 
if sys.executable != INTERP:
    os.execl(INTERP, INTERP, *sys.argv)
os.environ['SENTRY_CONF'] = "/home/user/.virtualenv/sentry2/sentry.conf.py"

import sentry.wsgi
```

believe it or not, that's it. If you look at the wsgi file in the sentry directory under the virtualenv install you will see it does all the importing of the django.core.handlers.wsgi and kicks off the correct application.

Comment: I've tried the same but I'm getting "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'application'", do you have any idea of what the problem might be?